# Set reverse DNS windows azure (new machines, not classic)

Tags: azure, dns, azure-powershell, azure-resource-manager, webmin

I need to set the reverse dns.

My machine is linux with Webmin.

My machine is not classical. It is new. The new machines have no cloud service, then the following article does not work!

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-reverse-dns-for-azure-cloud-services/

Get-AzureService does not recognize my machine.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

On the [link you provided](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-reverse-dns-for-azure-cloud-services/) scroll down to the comments. There is a discussion about Azure Resource Manager (new VMs, not classic).

It says the following. I highlighted the important part.

> This article was written before the Resource Providers for core Azure
>   were released, and as such it applies to Cloud Services created using
>   the old stack. **To configure reverse DNS on VMs created using the new
>   stack, you need to set the Reverse DNS property on the Public IP
>   Address resource.** As before, you need to demonstrate at create time
>   that you own the DNS name to which you want the reverse DNS record to
>   point - you can achieve that by creating an A record for that name
>   back to the Public IP address (or any other public IP address within
>   your subscription).

Answer (score 0):

for RM mode you need to do the following .

1.call New-AzureRmPublicIpAddress without a ReverseFqdn

2.register the IP address with the Fqdn you require

3.call New-AzureRmPublicIpAddress with ReverseFqdn registered in 2

4.register the IP address allocated in 3 to the Fqdn

5.delete IP address registered in 2

In case of classic, the public ip address is assigned to the cloud service. whereas in RM mode the public ip address is assigned to individual VMs.

Azure documentation states - "You can associate a Public IP address with a Virtual machine (VM) by assigning it to its network interface card (NIC). In case of a multi-NIC VM, you can assign it to the primary NIC only. You can assign either a dynamic or a static public IP address to a VM."